# Button fail in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i am defining a button and a edit text in the fragment class , but when i start it by pressing a list view from the main activity , it crashes , i tried putting the edit text in the the postData and it worked , still i need to get the button working as well and I cant switch it's place because i need to click it , anyway , i tried deleting the findviewbyid and just putting onclicklistiner but it gets me the same Nullexcpection as well , so i figured it might be something from the Fragment it self.

```
public class CommunityFragment extends Fragment {
final String myTag = "DocsUpload";
EditText pstTxt;
Button pstBtn;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //pstBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.PostButton);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_community,
            container, false);

    /*pstBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {*/
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    postData();

                }

                private void postData() {
                    try {
                        pstTxt = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.PostText);
                        String fullUrl = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1fbyAzU_gAD4QNtZnLkDkFqw32OpUnFh1S6Ugs-LAw7E/formResponse";
                        HttpRequest mReq = new HttpRequest();
                        String col1 = pstTxt.getText().toString();
                        String data = "entry_41657080="
                                + URLEncoder.encode(col1);
                        String response = mReq.sendPost(fullUrl, data);
                        Log.i(myTag, response);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            });
            t.start();

    /*  }
    });*/

    return rootView;
}
```

}
it works this way but when I play the button findview or the onclick it gets me this :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at info.slidingmenu.CommunityFragment.onCreateView(CommunityFragment.java:25)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:795)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:998)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1330)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:417)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of these two lines:

```
pstBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.PostButton);
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_community, container, false);
```

to this new order, with `getView()` replaced by the View `rootView` you just inflated:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_community, container, false);
pstBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.PostButton);
```

`getView()` is returning null, since the Fragment view is not readied yet (we haven't even returned from `onCreateView` when you try to call `getView()`).

Answer (score 0):

assuming your button is on fragment_community.xml layout, your oncreateview shoud be something like this

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {        

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_community,
                container, false);
        pstBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.PostButton);

        //i prefer to set listeners in onStart method but you can set it here also
        pstBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener());
        //....

       return rootView;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help , just like other comments , this worked very well